# Terminal Window always puts a path from .bashrc out how to fix?

Tags: bash, linux-mint, terminal

System: Linux Mint 20 (ubuntu)

So I installed emscripten the wasm compiler for C/C++ the other day and the path that was added to my bashrc always seems to start a new terminal shell with telling me that the paths have been added and the user color on the terminal is changed.

I can fix this by doing `source ~/.bashrc` and the normal color comes back but I was wondering what exactly is going on here and if there is a possible fix?

Here are some screenshots to show you how it looks:

[image: After doing source ~/.bashrc]

[image: New Terminal Shell]

Any insight or tips would be very much appreciated!

**Edit** these are the files you were looking to see:

.bashrc :

```
    # ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
    # see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
    # for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm|xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\h\[\033[01;34m\] \W \$\[\033[00m\] '
    else
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;34m\]\w \$\[\033[00m\] '
    fi
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h \w \$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

if [ -x /usr/bin/mint-fortune ]; then
     /usr/bin/mint-fortune
fi

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
alias paper='. /home/doom/Desktop/Minecraft/Paper/paper'

export PATH=$PATH:"$USER/QT/5.15.1/gcc_64/bin"

export PATH=$PATH:"$HOME/doom/Desktop/RoseDevelopment/emsdk"
export PATH=$PATH:"$HOME/doom/Desktop/RoseDevelopment/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin"
export PATH=$PATH:"$HOME/doom/Desktop/RoseDevelopment/emsdk/upstream/emscripten"
source "/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh"
alias startPg='~/pgAdmin4/venv/bin/python ~/pgAdmin4/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py'
```

and /etc/bash.bashrc :

```
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

# To enable the settings / commands in this file for login shells as well,
# this file has to be sourced in /etc/profile.

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, overwrite the one in /etc/profile)
# but only if not SUDOing and have SUDO_PS1 set; then assume smart user.
if ! [ -n "${SUDO_USER}" -a -n "${SUDO_PS1}" ]; then
  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi

# Commented out, don't overwrite xterm -T "title" -n "icontitle" by default.
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
#case "$TERM" in
#xterm*|rxvt*)
#    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'
#    ;;
#*)
#    ;;
#esac

# enable bash completion in interactive shells
#if ! shopt -oq posix; then
#  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
#  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#  fi
#fi

# sudo hint
if [ ! -e "$HOME/.sudo_as_admin_successful" ] && [ ! -e "$HOME/.hushlogin" ] ; then
    case " $(groups) " in *\ admin\ *|*\ sudo\ *)
    if [ -x /usr/bin/sudo ]; then
    cat <<-EOF
    To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
    See "man sudo_root" for details.
    
    EOF
    fi
    esac
fi

# if the command-not-found package is installed, use it
if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found -o -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
    function command_not_found_handle {
            # check because c-n-f could've been removed in the meantime
                if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
                elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
           /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1"
                   return $?
        else
           printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" >&2
           return 127
        fi
    }
fi
```

**Edit #2 :**
When I attempt to just run lines starting from the nvm command:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

After the line with the `# This loads nvm` command then the nvm command now works.

My `yarn` command does not work before but does after running:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
```

The minecraft paper server command does not work even after:

```
alias paper='. /home/doom/Desktop/Minecraft/Paper/paper'
```

The `emcc` command does however work before and after trying these lines:

```
export PATH=$PATH:"$HOME/doom/Desktop/RoseDevelopment/emsdk"
export PATH=$PATH:"$HOME/doom/Desktop/RoseDevelopment/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin"
export PATH=$PATH:"$HOME/doom/Desktop/RoseDevelopment/emsdk/upstream/emscripten"
```

The `startPg` command does not work before but does after inputting:

```
alias startPg='~/pgAdmin4/venv/bin/python ~/pgAdmin4/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py'
```

All of these commands work after I do `source ~/.bashrc`

**Edit #3**
So I got some interesting results here is my bashrc file:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

echo 'am i here?'

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm|xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]] ; then
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;31m\]\h\[\033[01;34m\] \W \$\[\033[00m\] '
    else
        PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] \[\033[01;34m\]\w \$\[\033[00m\] '
    fi
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h \w \$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

if [ -x /usr/bin/mint-fortune ]; then
     /usr/bin/mint-fortune
fi

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"
alias paper='. /home/doom/Desktop/Minecraft/Paper/paper'

export PATH=$PATH:"$USER/QT/5.15.1/gcc_64/bin"

echo 'hello world'

export PATH=$PATH:"$HOME/doom/Desktop/RoseDevelopment/emsdk"
export PATH=$PATH:"$HOME/doom/Desktop/RoseDevelopment/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin"
export PATH=$PATH:"$HOME/doom/Desktop/RoseDevelopment/emsdk/upstream/emscripten"

echo 'hi'
# source "/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh"
alias startPg='~/pgAdmin4/venv/bin/python ~/pgAdmin4/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgAdmin4.py'
```

I have commented out rvm. It still works before and after I do `source ~/.bashrc` I think this is because when installing rvm it puts you in an rvm group that gets access to the command I believe.

The echos above and below the emsdk (emcc) paths do not print out until I run `source ~/.bashrc` then they do run. I also put an echo at the very top of the file and it also doesn't run until I do the source of the file.

Here is what it looks like:

[image: New one]

**Edit #4**
I am sorry this is getting long but I was curious to see if this file might be causing problems:

.bash_profile

```
source "/home/doom/Desktop/RoseDevelopment/emsdk/emsdk_env.sh"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

When I commented both the rvm line and the emsdk_env.sh line the echo's went away. `rvm` command still works the emcc command no longer does. I still have a no color output until I do `source ~/.bashrc` and then most of my other commands nvm/yarn/paper/startPg work again.

This makes me think somehow my .bashrc file is not being loaded in on a fresh session?

Here is a look:

```
doom@doom-MacBookPro:~$ rvm
# It works here
doom@doom-MacBookPro:~$ yarn
-bash: yarn: command not found
doom@doom-MacBookPro:~$ rvm list
#This works here
doom@doom-MacBookPro:~$ emcc
-bash: emcc: command not found
doom@doom-MacBookPro:~$ paper
-bash: paper: command not found
doom@doom-MacBookPro:~$ nvm
-bash: nvm: command not found
doom@doom-MacBookPro:~$ source ~/.bashrc 
am i here?
hello world
hi
doom@doom-MacBookPro ~ $ nvm
#This works here
doom@doom-MacBookPro ~ $ paper
#This works here
doom@doom-MacBookPro ~ $ yarn
#This works here
```

Comment: Can you post your ~/.bashrc and your /etc/bashrc files?  Do obscure anything sensitive etc.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I added both files in an edit, don't think I have anything sensitive in them.

Comment: This is puzzling - from the symptoms I thought the system bashrc had extra lines in it, and re-sourcing your personal .bashrc was updating the colour.  But looking at those two files, its not clear where the prompt's colour change is happening.  The EXPORT lines should not print anything,  and they are before source "/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh"  which might be relevant.    I'm at a loss now, sorry.

Comment: No worries thank you for you time at looking into it either way. Yea I am also at a complete loss haha.

Comment: I am not sure if this helps but the command nvm ( right above the yarn path few lines up ) does not work until I do source ~/.bashrc . I only have one user doom and it says I am doom when I don't have color.

Comment: Try running each line one at a time, copy and paste them into an xterm/terminal window..

Comment: I added an Edit #2 at the bottom of my question.

Comment: my initial suspicion is also in the `rvm.sh` file. Maybe comment that out in .bashrc and see what happens. Another way of debugging is adding a bunch of `echo` in your .bashrc at different points, so you'll see if those messages are printed before or after each `echo` (make sure to put different message on each `echo`)

Comment: I added a third edit to my question. I commented out the rvm.sh line. And you can see what happens in my third picture. So i'm at a loss. It is like my bashrc file isn't loaded on a new terminal / when i logout then back in again?

I just got something strange. Even if I comment out the emsdk lines I still get the output and the colors / commands for most things not working. So is it possible those are coming from somewhere else?

Comment: If I go to "edit>preferences>command" and remove `run this command as a login shell` check I no longer get any messages and every command except emcc works. The color is also back. I got it from : `https://askubuntu.com/questions/161249/bashrc-not-executed-when-opening-new-terminal`
 However I believe this is not what I really want for the long term?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I may have finally figured it out. Going from the comments below my question. By the way thank you @Criggie and @msb.

It appears I can even turn back on my `run as command login shell` in my terminal preferences if I follow what @user3584014 did as the second answer to this question: `https://askubuntu.com/questions/161249/bashrc-not-executed-when-opening-new-terminal`
`https://askubuntu.com/a/768359/1138077`

Which is summed up pretty nicely:

```
In my case, simply the .bashrc loader lines were missing in .bash_profile

# include .bashrc if it exists
if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
fi
I added it manually and it worked with my fresh login
```

This allowed all of my commands including emcc to work and to get my color back right from the start.

[image: hello world]

```
Adding directories to PATH:
PATH += /home/doom/Desktop/RoseDevelopment/emsdk
PATH += /home/doom/Desktop/RoseDevelopment/emsdk/upstream/emscripten
PATH += /home/doom/Desktop/RoseDevelopment/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin

Setting environment variables:
EMSDK = /home/doom/Desktop/RoseDevelopment/emsdk
EM_CONFIG = /home/doom/Desktop/RoseDevelopment/emsdk/.emscripten
EM_CACHE = /home/doom/Desktop/RoseDevelopment/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cache
EMSDK_NODE = /home/doom/Desktop/RoseDevelopment/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin/node
doom@doom-MacBookPro ~ $ emcc
emcc: error: no input files
doom@doom-MacBookPro ~ $ yarn -v
1.22.10
doom@doom-MacBookPro ~ $ rvm -v
Warning! PATH is not properly set up, /home/doom/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/bin is not at first place.
         Usually this is caused by shell initialization files. Search for PATH=... entries.
         You can also re-add RVM to your profile by running: rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
         To fix it temporarily in this shell session run: rvm use ruby-2.5.3
         To ignore this error add rvm_silence_path_mismatch_check_flag=1 to your ~/.rvmrc file.
rvm 1.29.10 (manual) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
doom@doom-MacBookPro ~ $ nvm -v
0.36.0
doom@doom-MacBookPro ~ $
```

I still receive the emcc command echos from its being sourced in my

```
.bash_profile:
# include .bashrc if it exists
if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
fi

source "/home/doom/Desktop/RoseDevelopment/emsdk/emsdk_env.sh"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

However that is not much of a problem as long as everything else works from the start as opening multiple terminals up for things and then always having to do `source ~/.bashrc` was the real pain.